# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII carácter - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, pycharm

He hecho un programa sobre escribir una fecha y el programa te dice si esta bien o no.Todo esto a través de Python, tenemos instalado el Programa Pycharm.

el programa es el siguiente:

```
data= str(input("escribe fecha DD/MM/AAAA: "))  # introduccón de dades

errorDataTbl = {"Data vàlid.",  # errcod==0
                "Número de dia incorrecte.",  # errcod==1
                "Número de mes inexistent.",  # errcod==2
                "Número d’any fora del rang permès.",  # errcod==3
                "Format incorrecte.",  # errcod==4
                "Longitud del text incorrecta."}  #errcod==5

def errorInDate(Data):
    FormatoData="DD/MM/AAAA"

    if len(Data)==len(FormatoData):

        if Data[:2].isdigit() and Data[3:5].isdigit() and Data[6:].isdigit:
            DiesMes = [0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]       #para los bisiestos.
            dia = int(Data[:2])
            mes = int(Data[3:5])
            any = int(Data[6:])

            if any >= 2000 and any <= 2100:
                if not (any % 4==0 and any%100!=0 or any%400==0):
                    DiesMes [2]=28                                  #cuando es un año bisiesto febrero tiene 29 dias.

                if mes >= 1 and mes <= 12:
                    if DiesMes[mes] >= dia and dia > 0:
                        errcod=0

                    else: errcod=1
                else: errcod=2
            else: errcod=3
        else: errcod=4
    else: errcod=5

    return errcod

errcod= errorInDate(data)
print(errorDataTbl[errcod])
print("fi del programa")
```

El problema es que a mi me funciona correctamente, pero se lo he enviado a un amigo y no se si es porque tiene un MAC, pero le genera un error en el programa que es el siguiente:

```
file "/users/…., line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII carácter '\xc3' in file /users…..py on line 1 , but no encoding declared;http://Python..
```

alguien sabría decirme que pasa?

PD: mi amigo es nuevo en todo esto de la programacion y no tiene ni idea.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: En OSX (Mac) Python viene preinstalado, pero la versión que trae es la 2.7. Si tu amigo "no tiene ni idea", seguro que no habrá instalado Python3, y de ahi te vienen los problemas. En Python 2 es obligatorio declarar el encoding del fichero con un comentario inicial. También cambia la sintaxis de los `print()` y muchas más cosas. O escribes tu programa para Python2, o haces que tu amigo instale Python3, lo cual puede no ser apto para novatos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dice que no se a declarado un tipo de decodificacion y estas utilizando acentos.
solo debes agregar esto al principio del documento:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**quedaria:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
data= str(input("escribe fecha DD/MM/AAAA: "))  # introduccón de dades

errorDataTbl = {"Data vàlid.",  # errcod==0
                "Número de dia incorrecte.",  # errcod==1
                "Número de mes inexistent.",  # errcod==2
                "Número d’any fora del rang permès.",  # errcod==3
                "Format incorrecte.",  # errcod==4
                "Longitud del text incorrecta."}  #errcod==5

def errorInDate(Data):
    FormatoData="DD/MM/AAAA"

    if len(Data)==len(FormatoData):

        if Data[:2].isdigit() and Data[3:5].isdigit() and Data[6:].isdigit:
            DiesMes = [0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]       #para los bisiestos.
            dia = int(Data[:2])
            mes = int(Data[3:5])
            any = int(Data[6:])

            if any >= 2000 and any <= 2100:
                if not (any % 4==0 and any%100!=0 or any%400==0):
                    DiesMes [2]=28                                  #cuando es un año bisiesto febrero tiene 29 dias.

                if mes >= 1 and mes <= 12:
                    if DiesMes[mes] >= dia and dia > 0:
                        errcod=0

                    else: errcod=1
                else: errcod=2
            else: errcod=3
        else: errcod=4
    else: errcod=5

    return errcod

errcod= errorInDate(data)
print(errorDataTbl[errcod])
print("fi del programa")
```